# How to dynamically create a dropdown menu for any query by not specifying their column name

Tags: html, sql, drop-down-menu, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am creating an HTML form that requires dropdown menus of query values from a SQL database. I don't want to hardcode the form inputs but as much as possible dynamically create them, but I have noticed that when a dropdown menu for a query is made, a specified column name is required for an option. This forces me to hardcode each dropdown menu since I need to specify the column names for each one. Specifying the column names makes sense since a query can have multiple selected column names, but the queries I am using for the dropdown menus each only has one column name selected.

All I am trying to use to solve this issue are Coldfusion and HTML.

Below is the hardcoded dropdown menu.

```
<select name = "REV_WC">
     <option hidden disabled selected value>  </option>
         <cfoutput query = "#application.REV_WC#">
             <option value = "#REV_WC#"> #REV_WC# </option>
         </cfoutput>
</select>
```

I want to try to do something like this instead (not sure what the right syntax would be):

```
<select name = "Dd_NAME">
    <option hidden disabled selected value>  </option>
        <cfoutput query = "#db_query#">
            <option value = "#db_query.value#"> #db_query.value# </option>
        </cfoutput>
</select>
```

The query looks like this:

```
<cfscript>
    application.REV_WC = application.myDB.execute(sql = "SELECT DISTINCT REV_WC FROM MY_TABLE").getResult();
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is best to be explicit in most cases but the way to achieve what you are looking for is to use the `ColumnList` from the query result as the column name in array notation.

```
<option value = "#db_query[columnList][currentRow]#"> #db_query[columnList][currentRow]# </option>
```

If there is always one column then you are good but if you want to choose from list you can select them by index. For example for `SELECT ValueColumn, LabelColumn...`

```
<option value = "#db_query[listGetAt(columnList, 1)][currentRow]#"> #db_query[listGetAt(columnList, 2)][currentRow]# </option>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might serve your purpose.  Start with 3 lists.

```
<cfscript>
tableNames = "t1,t2,t3,etc";
fieldNames = "f1,f2,f3,etc";
queryNames = "q1,q2,q3,etc";
</cfscript>
```

Then, loop through the lists to run the queries and create your selects.

```
<cfloop from = "1" to = "#listlen(tableNames)#" index = "i">
<cfset thisTable = listGetAt(tableNames, i)>
<!--- same for fieldNames and queryNames --->

<cfquery name = "#thisQuery#">
select distinct #thisField# from #thisTable#
</cfquery>

<select name = "#thisTable#_#thisField#">
<cfoutput query = "#thisQuery#">
<option value = "#thisQuery.thisField#">"#thisQuery.thisField#"</option>
</cfselect>
</cfloop>
```

The code sample has not been tested and probably has mistakes, but it should show the general idea.